# How do I use DDMathParser with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ddmathparser

I'd like to use the [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) library with Objective-C, but it was written in Swift. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#import <MathParser/MathParser.h>

// ...

// This throws error:
Expression *e;
```

This doesn't build because the compiler can't find the "Expression" type declared by DDMathParser. I also tried switching my import statement to:

```
#import <MathParser/MathParser-Swift.h>
```

But still no luck.

I haven't been able to find any examples online of using this library in Objective-C. I'm new to Objective-C, so I don't even know what import statement to use; maybe other people find this common knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift version of DDMathParser wasn't written to be usable from Objective-C; it was written to be Swift-like.

If you need to use DDMathParser from Objective-C, I'd recommend using the code at the `objc` tag; that's the most recent version of the Objective-C code: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/releases/tag/objc